# when and where & why need to use Django - signals

Tags: django

when and where & why need to use Django - signals . I didn't understand Django signals can anyone can help in details with sample example thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only use signals to avoid introducing circular dependencies.

For more information [click here.](https://seddonym.me/2018/05/04/django-signals/)

Comment: can you tell me whats wrong in answer.